# What is our "elevator pitch"?

Tags: discussion

One of the Seven Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta is "What is our elevator pitch"?

This is a short description of what our site is all about. It can be a guiding principle for our site, and different versions of it can be used throughout the site as a tagline, a blurb, etc.

Please give one possible pitch in each answer.

Answer (score 8):

> This site is intended to give clear and effective answers to those with questions about teaching mathematics.

Comment: I've been trying to one-up this for a few hours. It can't be done.

Comment: How about omitting "those with", so it's just "...answers to questions about teaching mathematics"?  That would be clearer and probably amounts to the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

When I have a problem with my class, I usually feel like someone else already solved that problem, and I am curious what other people have done.

I usually come down to your office and ask you.

On this site, I can come down and ask **everyone**.